# Is there an asymptotic distribution expansion that does not go negative when truncated?

Tags: distributions, asymptotics

I am looking into a problem where I have a distribution that converges to the normal distribution as its parameters become large.  I am looking at the rate of this convergence, and seeking to describe its relation to the skewness and kurtosis of the distribution.  To do this, I am trying to find a series expansion for the distribution that can be truncated to yield an approximation that only depends on the first four moments.  I am familiar with the [Gram-Charlier series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series) and the [Edgeworth series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series#The_Edgeworth_series) for a distribution, which allow you to represent the density function of a continuous random variable as a weighted function of another target distribution, where the weighting depends only on the cumulants of the two distributions.  These are useful expansions, but one drawback is that when you truncate them the truncated version can go negative.

**Question:** Are there any good asymptotic expansions that do not go negative when you truncate them to use only a finite number of cumulants?

---

For example, if you have a continuous random variable $X$ with $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mu$ and $\mathbb{V}(X) = \sigma^2$ and you want to approximate it by the normal distribution, you can use the the [Gram-Charlier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series):

$$f(x) = \text{N}(x|\mu,\sigma^2) \times \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n(0,0,\kappa_3,...,\kappa_n)}{n! \sigma^n} \cdot \text{He}_n \Big( \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma} \Big),$$

where the $B_n$ terms are the [Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials) and the $\text{He}$ terms are the [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).  When you truncate this to the first four moments you get:

$$f(x) = \text{N}(x|\mu,\sigma^2) \times \Bigg[ 1 + \frac{\gamma}{3!} \cdot \text{He}_3 \Big( \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma} \Big) + \frac{\kappa - 3}{4!} \cdot \text{He}_4 \Big( \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma} \Big) \Bigg],$$

where $\gamma$ is the skewness and $\kappa$ is the kurtosis.  Unfortunately, this truncates expansion is sometimes negative, which is what I would like to avoid.